# How remove "Run | Debug" in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have successfully disabled suggestions in Visual Studio Code using the tips [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense).

However, how can I remove "Run | Debug" which shows up in the editor?
There is a picture:

[image: "Run | Debug" in the editor]

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_codelens

Comment: Is this a dart question?  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213588/836330

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below, and you will remove this 'Run | Debug' message.

VSCode "Run | Debug" Java:

[image: Screenshot]

Extensions -> 'Debugger for Java' -> Extensions Settings

[image: Screenshot]

Uncheck "Enable Run Debug Code Lens" in 'Debugger for Java' Extension Settings

[image: Screenshot]

Reopen the Java File

[image: Screenshot]