# How to disable "Run|Debug" line in vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am currently using Flutter with Dart. How do I permanently disable this annoying "Run|Debug" line in vscode?

[image]

Comment: If you disable the settings `Dart: Show Main Code Lens` or `Dart: Show Test Code Lens` does it go away?  I don't believe those are built-in to vscode, but are contributed by one of your extensions.

Comment: @Mark Okay go ahead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That `Run | Debug` is not built-in to vscode.  It must be contributed by one of your extensions.  These seem like likely culprits:

`Dart: Show Main Code Lens`

// Whether to show CodeLens actions in the editor for quick running/debugging scripts with main functions.

---

`Dart: Show Test Code Lens`

// Whether to show CodeLens actions in the editor for quick running/debugging tests.

---

In case people get here because there is a `Debug` or `Run` in their package.json, that is a separate issue and answer, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358131/how-to-disable-debug-from-showing-in-package-json/62368407?r=SearchResults&s=1|57.9327#62368407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358131/how-to-disable-debug-from-showing-in-package-json/62368407?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C57.9327#62368407)

Answer (score 7):

Just disable `Enable Code Lens` in `jest` plugin.

It's very annoying! When you write test code, small `Debug` text shows on top of a test (above `it` method) when it fails.

[image: Debug]

During programming, it constantly shows and hides, causing lines of code move up and down a bit. It's terrible experience. Fortunately, easy to disable.

[image: VS Code Configuration]

After disabling it, we still have test status feedback:

[image: test feedback]

Comment: In what way are Jest / JavaScript related to the question which is about Flutter / Dart?

Answer (score 6):

Add this line to your settings:

```js
"editor.codeLens": false,
```

Or do this in settings:
[image: code lens annoying in vs code]

Answer (score 2):

In VSC settings, search for "Pester Code Lens".
You can disable the first option.

[Disable Pester Code Lens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTmrC.png)

Answer (score 1):

you just open your vs Code Setting -> Text Editor -> Code Lean [Check mark this Box][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Java Extension paste this in your settings.json file

```js
"java.debug.settings.enableRunDebugCodeLens": false
```