# Run | Debug buttons on line 3 - Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to remove / hide annoying buttons on line 3 when I run my Flutter application.
Problem is when I am editing code that buttons keep hiding and showing and my code going up - down.

How it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqkjD.jpg

Any advice ?

Comment: It is a CodeLens line. Find an option in your test runner to disable it

Answer (score 0):

disable the settings `Dart: Show Main Code Lens` or `Dart: Show Test Code Lens.`

This occurs due to codelens

I referred this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213143/how-to-disable-rundebug-line-in-vscode)