# VS code some helper lines annoyingly appearing and disappearing

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are some helper lines (look at `run test | debug test` in the picture) when I'm writing codes, they frequently appear and disappear and move my code! it's very annoying especially when there are so many tests (as each have one of this helpers).

I don't know even what to search to disable this.

appears:

[image]

disappears:

[image]

Comment: search the settings of your language for `Codelens`

Comment: For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213588/836330.

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74455784/12972198